# Valet-PHP installation fails due to syntax errors in .make file

Tags: laravel, homebrew, laravel-valet

I am following [this](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/valet#overview) guide to install valet-plus. Something seems to be wrong in the brew files though. When running the `brew install valet-php@7.4 --build-from-source` install command, I get the following error:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/markusreis/Library/Logs/Homebrew/valet-php@7.4/03.make:
    virtual bool operator==(const BreakIterator&) const = 0;
            ~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [ext/intl/breakiterator/breakiterator_methods.lo] Error 1
1 error generated.
make: *** [ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.lo] Error 1
In file included from /private/tmp/valet-phpA7.4-20220304-86241-1rnurk6/php-7.4.16/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_methods.cpp:17:
/private/tmp/valet-phpA7.4-20220304-86241-1rnurk6/php-7.4.16/ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_internal.h:42:17: error: virtual function 'operator==' has a different return type ('UBool' (aka 'signed char')) than the function it overrides (which has return type 'bool')
                virtual UBool operator==(const BreakIterator& that) const;
                        ~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/70.1/include/unicode/brkiter.h:127:18: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual bool operator==(const BreakIterator&) const = 0;
            ~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [ext/intl/breakiterator/codepointiterator_methods.lo] Error 1

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  https://github.com/henkrehorst/homebrew-php/issues
```

I also tried without `--build-from-source`, but then I get a SSL and also there I find no way around...

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dl.bintray.com:443

Error: valet-php@8.0: Failed to download resource "valet-php@8.0"
Download failed: https://dl.bintray.com/henkrehorst/valet-php/valet-php%408.0-8.0.3.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
```

I am absolutely clueless what to do with this. I also tried `8.0` and `7.3` - same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: having the same error

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here - https://github.com/henkrehorst/homebrew-php/issues/158#issuecomment-1059516450
It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi! Please edit your answer to add a summary of the solution. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info for details.

Answer (score 0):

`brew edit valet-php@7.4` - If I update to use PHP 7.4.28, installation is successful.

```
url "https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.28.tar.xz"
sha256 "9cc3b6f6217b60582f78566b3814532c4b71d517876c25013ae51811e65d8fce"
```